# Calculating node depths of all nodes in a Binary Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to solve the [Node Depths question from Algoexpert](https://www.algoexpert.io/questions/Node%20Depths). The problem requires you to calculate the sum of depths of all the nodes in a given binary tree. For example, given this tree -

```
          1
       /     \
      2       3
    /   \   /   \
   4     5 6     7
 /   \
8     9
```

the sum should be 16.

I wrote a recursive solution to it, which I think is correct, but interestingly enough, only the first test passes, while the remaining test cases fail. Here is my solution-

```
import java.util.*;

class Program {

  // static variable to hold the final sum
  private static int finalSum = 0;

  public static int nodeDepths(BinaryTree root) {
        // Write your code here.
        int runningSum = 0;
        depthHelper(root.left, runningSum);
        depthHelper(root.right, runningSum);
        return finalSum;
  }
    
    private static void depthHelper(BinaryTree node, int runningSum) {
        if(node == null) return;
        runningSum++;
        finalSum += runningSum;
        depthHelper(node.left, runningSum); 
        depthHelper(node.right, runningSum);
    }

  static class BinaryTree {
    int value;
    BinaryTree left;
    BinaryTree right;

    public BinaryTree(int value) {
      this.value = value;
      left = null;
      right = null;
    }
  }
}
```

The algorithm itself is fairly simple.

There is a `runningSum` variable (initialized to -1 to account for the root) to which I add 1, every time I visit a new node (ie: one level down from it's parent). And, the value of this `runningSum` variable is added to the `finalSum` variable at each recursive call.

As an example, at node 2, `runningSum` is `1`, and this gets added to `finalSum` which was `0`. Now `finalSum` becomes `1`. Same for node `3`, after which `finalSum` becomes `2`. At node `4`, `runningSum` becomes `2` and `finalSum` becomes `4`.

The first test case passes, and I get this message -

[image]

But then, all the subsequent cases fail. I think *what may be happening is* - the output from the previous test case execution is not cleared, and somehow gets added to the result of the current test case execution.

Here's why I think that may be the reason -

```
 1. Test case 2 - our code output - 0,  your code output - 16
 2. Test case 3 - our code output - 1,  your code output - 17
 3. Test case 4 - our code output - 2,  your code output - 19
 4. Test case 5 - our code output - 4,  your code output - 23
 5. Test case 6 - our code output - 21,  your code output - 44
 6. Test case 7 - our code output - 42,  your code output - 86
```

Notice how the result from a previous execution isn't cleared and gets added to the "our code output" of the subsequent execution. For instance, in the second test case, the "your code output" result shows `16` which was actually the result of the first test case.

Is this due to the usage of a global `static` variable in the code? But I've used the same approach several times on Leetcode, and it worked well there.

Or is there a different bug in my algorithm?

PS - I know using screenshots is frowned upon here, but there is a chance this is a platform-specific issue, so I had to use it.

Comment: Try `int temp=finalSum;  finalsum=0; return temp;` at the end of `nodeDepths()`.

Comment: Yes! That worked, all test cases pass, thank you!. So it is a platform specific issue then. What exactly is the problem with the way their tests are run, so I can submit a bug report?

Comment: Maybe they run tests with only one object of your class. yeah i think you should report it!

Comment: I would rather just reset the finalSum where you also initialize runningSum to 0 than using a temp variable. Note that this implementation is not working if requests are made in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

In my opition it is not a bug that this behavior occurs. It is due to making everything static. There are many possibilities to avoid this problem. Two of them explained here:

Using static methods but with stateless class:

```
public static int nodeDepths(BinaryTree root) {
    // Write your code here.
    return depthHelper(root.left, 1) + depthHelper(root.right, 1);
}

private static int depthHelper(BinaryTree node, int sum) {
    if (node == null) return 0;
    return sum + depthHelper(node.left, sum + 1) + depthHelper(node.right, sum + 1);
}
```

Create an object (becomes more useful if you are not doing just one operation on the object):

```
public static int nodeDepths(BinaryTree root) {
    // Write your code here.
    return new Program().depthSum(root); // call to non-static method
    // like this you can use your original implementation, but the
    // class variable (finalSum) has to be non-static too
}
```

Both implementations are thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like their testing platform runs tests with one object of your class. So you should clear `finalSum` at the end of `nodeDepths()` method:

```
public static int nodeDepths(BinaryTree root) {
    // Write your code here.
    int runningSum = 0;
    depthHelper(root.left, runningSum);
    depthHelper(root.right, runningSum);
    int temp=finalSum;  
    finalsum=0; 
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Setting `finalSum` to 0 at the top of the function would be simpler.